# Shortcut for indexers in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, indexer

I'm using an indexer in a class in C#, but I'm wondering if there is by default a shortcut for making indexers (like for example '`cw` tab tab' for `Console.WriteLine()`). Does anyone knows if this exists?

Here's my code (with indexer) for the class 'Person':

```
public string SurName { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string Birthplace { get; set; }

public string this[int index]
{
    set
    {
        switch (index)
        {
            case 0:
                this.SurName = value;
                break;
            case 1:
                this.FirstName = value;
                break;
            case 2:
                this.Birthplace = value;
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");
        }
    }
    get
    {
        switch (index)
        {
            case 0: return this.SurName;
            case 1: return this.FirstName;
            case 2: return this.Birthplace;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

-Jérémy

Comment: The Code snippet is called indexer, you can use it by typing ind + tab + tab, or even i + tab + tab (as soon as it's marked in the the intellisense)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Visual C# Code Snippets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat.aspx)

> indexer
>
> Creates an indexer declaration.
>
> Inside a class or a struct.

[image]

So, type <kbd>`ind`</kbd> and hit <kbd>`Tab`</kbd> twice. This generates;

```
public object this[int index]
{
     get { /* return the specified index here */ }
     set { /* set the specified index to value here */ }
}
```

> However, is there also a snippet that fills in the get and set
>   automatically?

*Hmm*, I did not tried this before but I opened `propfull.snippet` and it seems like;

```
        ....
        <Literal>
            <ID>field</ID>
            <ToolTip>The variable backing this property</ToolTip>
            <Default>myVar</Default>
        </Literal>
    </Declarations>
    <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[private $type$ $field$;

public $type$ $property$
{
    get { return $field$;}
    set { $field$ = value;}
}
....
```

And `indexer.snippet` looks like;

```
....
....
<Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[$access$ $type$ this[$indextype$ index]
{
    get {$end$ /* return the specified index here */ }
    set { /* set the specified index to value here */ }
}]]>
....
```

So, if you define `<Literal><ID>field</ID>...</Literal>` part in your `indexer.snippet` and if you change it's getter and setter like;

```
public object this[int index]
{
   get { return $field$; }
   set { $field$ = value; }
}
```

this *might* work if everything is good. By the way, it this works, it will create a private field additional to indexer. Those snippets are in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#` folder for Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't know that it was called a 'Code Snippet'. However, is there also a snippet that fills in the get and set automatically?

Comment: @Jérémy I did _not_ tried this way but it should work. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for everything. I'll try it out.

Comment: @Jérémy Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can create code snippets, take a look at this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx
or this page for existing code snippets
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat.aspx